# How am I able to connect to mqtt server with wrong credentials?

Tags: arduino, mqtt, nodemcu

I gave the wrong credentials in the arduino for the mqtt server, but still i am able to connect to the mqtt server and receive messages from the nodemcu board.
Here is the code :

```
const char* mqttserver="broker.mqtt-dashboard.com";
 const char* clientid="clie"; //client1
 const char* username="sampleCli"; //sampleclient
 const char* password="clien"; //client123
```

i have given the wrong clientid as well as the username and password. I am using mqtt box as a mqtt broker.

Here is the code to connect to the mqtt broker

```
if(client.connect(clientid,username,password))
{
  Serial.println("connected");
  client.publish("topic1","connected");
}
else
{
  Serial.println("failed to connect");
  Serial.print(client.state());
  delay(5000);
}
```

I dnt get any "failed to connect" statement in the serial monitor, and also the mqtt broker recieves messages from the nodemcu board.
What mistake am i making?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that you don't have the server setup to correctly require a password.

Try using something like [mosquitto_pub](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto_pub-1.html) to confirm the server is behaving as you expect then re-try the client code.